# How to use PyTorch DataParallel with non-tensor input

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm building an image segmentation model using the PyTorch Mask-RCNN, and I'd like to parallelize it across GPUs. However, the PyTorch MaskRCNN requires that the target is a dictionary of `{key: Tensor}` with specific keys rather than a single Tensor.

On a single GPU it runs fine, but when wrapped with `torch.nn.DataParallel` it returns this error:
`chunk expects at least a 1-dimensional tensor`, which I expect happens because it's given a list of dictionaries instead of a Tensor.

The code relevant to the error is given here, where the error occurs on the last line.

```
    for images, targets in data_loader:

        images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]

        loss_dict = model(images, targets)
```

Is there an established way of dealing with this problem?